# Access the_post() contents in a custom sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code in  `single-legislacion.php` page:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
$args = array(
    'order'       => 'ASC',
    'post_type'   => 'attachment',
    'post_parent' => $thePostID,
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'numberposts' => 1
);

$attachments = get_posts( $args );
if ( $attachments ) :
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) : ?>
        <div class="BaseIco">
            <a class="IcoDescargas" href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID, true ); ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/ico_descargas.png"><br>
                Descargar PDF
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach;
endif;
?>
```

Because I am using [Table of Content Plus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/table-of-contents-plus/) plugin and have not found a way to display the generated TOC outside of `the_content()` itself, the only solution I have is to display it through a widget on a sidebar. Now, my question is: can I access `the_post()` content, like attachments for example, in a custom sidebar? How?

Also if any knows any variant to show the TOC outside the content, I'll be graceful if can share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think so. `the_post()` only works inside of the loop, sidebars are usually rendered outside of it.

However, you can use `get_post` with global `$post`, i.e.:

```
global $post;

$p = get_post($post->ID);
```